# how to set the authorization in html email

Tags: html, authorization

I am sending an html email which refers to some images on amazon s3. The images need an authorization in http header. Specifically they need this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: '
```

How can I provide that empty space authorization the the html email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

HTML provides no means to specify custom HTTP headers for requests.

If you were using a *browser*, you could use JavaScript with XMLHttpRequest to make the request and then convert the response into a `data:` URI and use that as the src of the image. HTML formatted email has no such option though.